# Pytest: How can I execute Python Code after Tests?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a pytest code that executes fine. But after the tests declared in the `1_test.py` file, I want to execute python code that automatically sends information to another application. I have encountered `pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus)`, but since I have more than 1 testfile I want only to execute the code after 1_test.py file and not after the other testfiles. Are there any other possibilities to run python code after all tests in 1_test.py are finished?

For clarification:

I currently have a pytest file called `1_test.py` and a list with tests that I have defined in another file.

there are several tests defined like:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("param1, param2", test_list)
def test_1:

assert x=y

@pytest.mark.parametrize("param1, param2", test_list)
def test_2:

assert a=b
```

I want to store all failure messages in a list for example called failure_list and send it's content to a third party application using HTTP POST for further analysis. I'm currently running it using pytest in VS Code. The tests are working fine but afterwards I don't know how to trigger the post statement, since further code is not being executed after the tests. I also can't add the post statement inside the tests because I need all failure messages before posting it.

Comment: This sounds a little like an XY problem (https://xyproblem.info). What exactly are you trying to achieve? Also, is this running locally, in a pipeline, or where?

Comment: I'm currently running it through the VS Code Pytest GUI. What I want to achieve is to gather all failure messages and send it to a another application using a POST Statement for further usage. Later it will run in a Pipeline.

Comment: Sounds like you need a module-scoped fixture (teardown code goes after `yield`).

Comment: @MrBean Bremen can you elaborate?

Comment: You can put your code into a module-scoped fixture (`@pytest.fixture(scope="module", autouse=True): yield; do_your_stuff()`). You may check [the documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/fixtures.html).

Comment: Personally, I'd just create artifacts with the logs, coverage etc. and then the other application can fetch the artifacts as required.